# Cant create VpnNativeProfile by VpnManagerAgent after Anniversary Update

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, vpn

[VpnManagementAgent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.vpn.vpnmanagementagent.aspx)

[VpnNativeProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.vpn.vpnnativeprofile.aspx)

`AddProfileFromObjectAsync` always return `VpnManagementErrorStatus.Other`

details about `VpnNativeProfile` not changed
before anniversary update all this worked

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 [Version 14.0.25425.01 update
>   3]
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework [Version 4.6.01586]

Comment: Can you provide code? When does this happen, what are the steps to reproduce it?...

Comment: This is a known bug/problem. If you want a fix, please contact Microsoft support. http://aka.ms/storesupport, click "Get Advanced Development support"

Answer (score 0):

This bug has since been fixed in the Creators Update 15063 and was also backwards ported to the anniversary update.
You should now be able to create the VPN profile